# How to prevent global defaults from overriding 'filetype=vim' specific settings in .vimrc when automatically sourcing .vimrc?

Tags: vim, autocmd

## Context

I have my `.vimrc` automatically being sourced with:

```
autocmd! BufWritePost ~/.vimrc source ~/.vimrc
```

I also set defaults for spacing:

```
set tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
```

Later on, I use the `FileType` event to override the spacing default above with filetype-specific spacing:

```
" Syntax of these languages is fussy over tabs & spaces¬
autocmd FileType make setlocal ts=8 sts=8 sw=8 noexpandtab¬
autocmd FileType yaml setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab¬                                                   

" Customisations based on house-style (arbitrary)
autocmd FileType sh setlocal ts=4 sts=4 sw=4 expandtab
autocmd FileType vim setlocal ts=4 sts=4 sw=4 expandtab
```

## Problem

The problem I am having is that sourcing my `.vimrc` will set the default values, but will not trigger the `FileType` event. This means that when I do a `:write` to my `.vimrc` <s>while editting a file with filetype-specific spacing</s>, the filetype-specific spacings get overridden by the defaults!

**UPDATE**: As pointed out by Ingo, the issue only arises in `.vimrc` and does not occur in any other files.

## Example

As an example, when I am working on my `.vimrc`, initially the file-specific spacing (`ts=4 sts=4 sw=4 expandtab`) is enabled, but after I make some arbitrary change in my `.vimrc`, the default spacing (`tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab`) is loaded but my file-specific spacing is NOT loaded (since the `FileType` event was not triggered by a write to my `.vimrc`) leaving me with the default spacing!

## My question(s)

How can I override the default spacing with filetype specific spacings and preserve these even when auto-sourcing `.vimrc`?

If possible, I would like to accomplish this without getting rid of the autocmd's. Is that possible?

My hunch is that I should somehow manually trigger the FileType event when sourcing `.vimrc` Can this be done and is this the recommended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by grouping the sourcing `autocmd` with another `autocmd` with the same event

```
" Reload changes to .vimrc automatically  
autocmd BufWritePost ~/.vimrc source ~/.vimrc | setlocal filetype=vim
```

---

I had tried this earlier, but I was also using the `AirlineRefresh` command for [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) as such:

```
autocmd BufWritePost ~/.vimrc source ~/.vimrc | AirlineRefresh | setlocal filetype=vim
```

which was giving me this error:

```
E488: Trailing characters:  AirlineRefresh | setlocal filetype=vim
```

Switching the order of `AirlineRefresh` and `set local filetype=vim` fixed the error and results in the desired behavior:

```
autocmd BufWritePost ~/.vimrc source ~/.vimrc | setlocal filetype=vim | AirlineRefresh
```

Answer (score 2):

Though you've very clearly described the problem, I doubt that this is happening.

As you're correctly using `:setlocal` for the filetype-specific settings, and `:set` in your `~/.vimrc`, the sourcing of the latter will only affect the global defaults (and the current buffer, which is your `.vimrc` during the `BufWritePost` event). To affect other buffers, there would need to be a `:bufdo` command in your `.vimrc`.

You can check this with

```
:verbose set ts? sts? sw? et?
```

To avoid that your `.vimrc` settings are overridden with the global settings, you can append this:

```
if expand('%:t') ==# '.vimrc'
    setlocal filetype=vim
endif
```

Comment: Good point about this only happening in <code>.vimrc</code>! Your suggestion worked, but it needed to be lower in the <code>.vimrc</code> file that the global default declaration to work.

Comment: Yes, that's correct; I thought this was obvious, so I didn't mention it. Appending this to the original autocmd (as per your answer) probably works, too; it may just cause problems with `:wall`.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so it wasn't immediately obvious but looking back, it does seem obvious now :)

Answer (score 0):

`:bufdo e` will do it but I couldn't just add it to my `.vimrc`. It will also remove syntax highlighting which is not so good.

`:h bufdo` execute the command in each buffer in the buffer list

`:h :e` re-edit the current file